# Sorting records by date while inserting a potential reply after original post

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I realize the title is not clear, it's the best I could manage.
I have a table that holds user comments. A comment can have one single reply, indicated as such by the replyTo field not being 0 but the postId of the comment it refers to.

```
CREATE TABLE user_comments (
  postId INT NOT NULL,
  postDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
  replyTo INT NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
  postText VARCHAR(1000)
)
INSERT INTO user_comments (postId, postDate, replyTo, postText) VALUES(1, '20200930 10:34:09 AM', 0, 'comment 1')
INSERT INTO user_comments (postId, postDate, replyTo, postText) VALUES(2, '20201001 08:20:06 PM', 0, 'comment 2')
INSERT INTO user_comments (postId, postDate, replyTo, postText) VALUES(3, '20201002 09:10:11 AM', 1, 'reply to 1')
```

I am trying to get all the comments by date (descending) but if a particular comment has a reply (comment 1 has one), have it appear after the comment in question.
So something like this:

```
postContext    postId      postDate                  postText
2              2           '20201001 08:20:06 PM'    comment 2
1              1           '20200930 10:34:09 AM'    comment 1
1              3           '20201002 09:10:11 AM'    reply to 1
```

Where postContext would be generated by the query and be used in my code to "group" a comment and its reply.

I am pretty sure a PARTITION BY based query could do the trick, but I just can't find the right way to achieve it.
Thanks for any pointer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Self Join, and then `ISNULL` (Or `COALESCE` if you prefer) on a couple of the columns to get the value you want:

```sql
SELECT ISNULL(p.postId,uc.postid) AS PostContext,
       uc.postId,
       uc.postDate,
       uc.postText
FROM dbo.user_comments uc
     LEFT JOIN dbo.user_comments p ON uc.replyTo = p.postId
ORDER BY ISNULL(p.postDate,uc.postDate) DESC,
         uc.postDate ASC;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=71ebba66d7ce8ce93ac25599baaf019f)